# GET Longitude and Latitude from image

Tags: php, gps, exif

I want to get Latitude and Longitude from uploaded image. I have read and found `exif_read_data` function. But It doesn't return GPS information. My server php.ini say
[image]

And I am getting as below

```
$exif = exif_read_data('pulbic/images/uploaded_photos/01af_ae31.jpg');
```

And `print_r($exif)` only shows

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => 01af_ae31.jpg
    [FileDateTime] => 1403961175
    [FileSize] => 32658
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => COMMENT
    [COMPUTED] => Array
    (
        [html] => width="720" height="540"
        [Height] => 540
        [Width] => 720
        [IsColor] => 1
    )

   [COMMENT] => Array
    (
        [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality

    )

)
```

I have taken images from smart phones as well as from webcam of my laptop. I want to have `GPSLongitude, GPSLongitudeRef , GPSLatitude, GPSLatitudeRef` information using `exif`.

I have checked with an online exif tool. Same image has GPS headers but php function is not returning it.

Any guideline will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your script/application resize or manipulate the image before saving it? I see there "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality" that means something edited the image. In that case you might be losing your metadata.

Comment: @ggioffreda Thank you for your response. I need to see it because the script I am working on isn't mine. Let me see.

Comment: I'm quite sure something manipulated your image. If you want to check, try and replace the image 01af_ae31.jpg with the original one taken from your phone (maybe rename it to match the filename you want) and see if that works. If it does you need to turn off the image manipulation or grab the information you need before it's done.

Comment: @ggioffreda if you answer this I will accept the answer